# get Full message from telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want to get the full message sent by the person's ID in telegram bot , including all the attached files, such as a photo , audio, image, or a caption and photo ... , and send it to another person's ID. I don't want it to be forward , I want to be sent!
I receive all updates this way:

```
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

my code :

```
    <?php
const apiKey='112';
$channels=[
    '1'=>'-1001233909561',
    '2'=>'-1001198102700',
];
const admin='668400001';
//-------------------------------------------------------- End Channels and ADMIN Info
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$json_data=json_encode($data);
file_put_contents('data.json', $json_data);
function bot($method, $datas = [])
{
    $url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . apiKey . "/" . $method;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($datas));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch))
    {
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    }
    else
    {
        return json_decode($res);
    }
}

 function forwardMessage($messageId)
{

    bot('forwardMessage',[
        'chat_id'=>backupChannelId,
        'from_chat_id'=>firstChannelId,
        'message_id'=>$messageId,
    ]);
}

function sendMessage($toChannel,$message)
{

}



?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the text and all the attachments of all messages sent to the bot. For example, the text of the message is in [`update`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update)`->`[`message`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message)`-> text`.

```php
$text = $data['message']['text'];
$audio = $data['message']['audio'];
```

The easiest way to send the exact same massage to another chat is by forwarding it, otherwise you have to search for all the possible attachments in the [message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object and, if present, send them to the other chat with the corrisponding method ([`sendPhoto`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto), [`sendAudio`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendaudio) etc.).

---

**Tip:**

use

```php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

instead of

```php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

More details [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)